# jQuery Hover Intent, sub menu disappears / buggy when interval is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hoverintent

I am currently using the jQuery Hover Intent plugin to add an initial delay when triggering the hover of a menu.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="link hover"><a href="#">Hover</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub hover">
     <h1>Sub Section</h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Vars
var timeout;

// Show Menu
function showMenu() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('.sub').fadeIn(50);
}

// Hide Menu
function hideMenu() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.sub').fadeOut(50);
    }, 100);
}

// Settings
var config = {
    interval: 50, // time between reading/comparing mouse coordinates
    timeout: timeout, // time before out function is called
    over: showMenu,
    out: hideMenu
};

// Initialise Hover
$('.hover').hoverIntent(config);
```

In the config, when the interval is set to 0 switching between the containers works fine.

When i set the interval greater than 0 hovering in and out of the containers becomes buggy (sub menu flickers and disappears). However i need the interval set for the initial delay.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfx7ucnw/4/

Comment: Actually it is not gonna work the way you think it would.
You gave same class to Menu and Sub Menu 'hover'
And in jQuery you wrote $('.hover').hoverIntent(config);
This line will Initialize hoverIntent on both Menu and Submenu elements.
So when you use 0 as interval then everything works fine, as HoverIntent's showMenu and hideMenu callbacks as attached with both elements.

Comment: You have to write your own code/logic to prevent SubMenu from hiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT - new answer

OK mate. If you has this html and you can't change that try to `.stop(true)` the `fadeOut` animation every time you trigger `mouseenter` or `over` to prevent the `fadeOut`.

I don't know if this is possibile with `hoverIntent` plugin, but you can use this code instead:

```
$(".hover").on({
    "mouseenter" : function(e){
        $(".sub").stop(true);
        $(".sub").fadeIn();
    },
    "mouseleave" : function(e){
        $(".sub").delay(50).fadeOut();
    },
})
```

### EDIT #2 - PREVENT ACCIDENTALLY OVER

To prevent accidentally over simple add a delay to the fadeIn effect if user is "over" the `.hover` button (but not when is over `.sub`).

And also in `mouseleave` add `.stop(true)` to prevent the fadeIn on "fast moving":

```
$(".hover,.sub").on({
    "mouseenter" : function(e){
        _delay = ($(this).hasClass("hover")) ? 200 : 0 ;
        $(".sub").stop(true);
        $(".sub").delay(_delay).fadeIn();
    },
    "mouseleave" : function(e){
        $(".sub").stop(true);
        $(".sub").delay(50).fadeOut();
    },
})
```

Work with delay and fadeIn time to create the best performance.

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hfx7ucnw/8/

### OLD answer

It's a problem that I know.

From my experience I can tell you that the only way to create a "dropdown" or a "submenu" that show on `mouseover` and hide on `mouseleave` is to indent the **child element to parent** I edit Your fiddle to show you my way.

with some simple change on `CSS` and `HTML`

http://jsfiddle.net/hfx7ucnw/5/

Tell me if this way is your.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is the most common way to create a dropdown menu however the way my site is structured means that the menu and sub menu have to be separate, which works perfectly fine without the initial hover delay, thanks anyway!

Comment: ... if you create a costum handler widhout use `hoverIntent ` you can create something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hfx7ucnw/7/. Take a Look.

Comment: Yes but using the delay only delays the fadeIn animation whereas the hover intent adds a initial hover delay to the element.

The purpose of this is to stop users accidentally triggering the menu unintentionally.

Comment: edit my answer. Take a look to `EDIT #2 - PREVENT ACCIDENTALLY OVER` @RyanErrington

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not going to work the way you think it would. You gave same class to Menu and Sub Menu 'hover' And in jQuery you wrote $('.hover').hoverIntent(config); This line will Initialize hoverIntent on both Menu and Submenu elements. So when you use 0 as interval then everything works fine, as HoverIntent's showMenu and hideMenu callbacks as attached with both elements.

So in end, You have to write your own code/logic to prevent SubMenu from hiding.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, yes that makes perfect sense although i believe i'm already preventing the menu from hiding through using timeout / clearTimeout.